# How to get git clone to play nice with Docker cache?

Tags: git, docker, caching

When I clone a repository twice, eg.:

```
git clone <repo_X> --depth 1 clone1
git clone <repo_X> --depth 1 clone2
```

and then do a diff

```
diff -r clone1 clone2
```

This shows differences:

```
Binary files clone1/.git/index and clone2/.git/index differ
...
diff -r clone1/.git/logs/HEAD clone2/.git/logs/HEAD
...
diff -r clone1/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD 
...
```

It seems that among others the time when cloning is recorded in a file.

I want to add some repositories to a Docker Image. Docker uses its cache when the files are not changed. Unfortunately after a clone Docker always invalidates the cache due to the changed files.

1. Is it somehow possible to have two clones of a repo result in exactly the same files? (Note.: I don't want to remove the .git directory as I want to be able to use git inside the image to check the version of the repo.)
2. Is it possible to let Docker ignore the .git folder when it comes to caching (Note that the .git folder still must be added to the image, so .dockerignore is not an option?)

Comment: How about using docker COPY command to move your pre-cloned git folder from host file system to image?

Comment: This won't work: 
1. I clone repo in folder X

2. Use COPY to add folder X to the image 

3. Build the image

4. Delete X

5. Make a fresh clone of X

Now when you rebuild the docker image, docker will not use the cache for the COPY X step.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my bad, I thought repo content stays same between 2 images and you don't need to delete X and reclone again.

Comment: A different user on the same machine will also work on making modifications to the Docker Image so he will clone a repo as well. It was expected that Docker would use its cache if the repo does not change. But alas even when the cloned repo is at the same commit some files are changed according to Docker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use new Docker's BuildKit's feature `--mount=cache`. Toy example of Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt \
    apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -yq git
RUN echo A00
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/tmp/git_cache/ \
    git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/qtox/qtox/ /tmp/git_cache/qtox/; \
    cd /tmp/git_cache/qtox/ && git pull && cp -r ./ /tmp/my_qtox/
RUN echo B00
```

Above dockerfile can be built by command:

`sudo env DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -f Dockerfile .`

notice presence of `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` environment variable, it is necessary to enable all BuildKit's features inside docker build. You can read about BuildKit's features [here](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md).

For example I cloned [qTox](https://github.com/qtox/qtox/) repo above as it is quite huge.

`--mount=cache` feature automatically creates temporary directory meant for caching and mounts it into `/tmp/git_cache/` (target) inside container. If some previous layers changed, e.g. `echo A00` changed to `echo A01` then this cloning is done immediately without delay because it is just taken from cache.

Also as you requested using this cache will make cloning repository being totally same. Only when new commits appear inside repository then `git pull` is done and repository changes. Unless there new commits this cached repository will stay the same. Hence you'll have identical git repo every time when you run docker build again.

Only rarely Docker will automatically delete cached directory if it wasn't used for long time or if you have low disk free space.

As you can see from docker-file above final git repo will appear inside `/tmp/my_qtox/` folder of container. You may change this path to whatever you need for your case.

Also you may have noticed that I used same caching mechanism when installing APT packages. This is very handy because when image is rebuilt all packages are not redownloaded from remote Ubuntu server, but taken from cached directory. It is useful when previous docker layers before apt install have changed or when you add new apt packages to installation list, in both cases apt install will re-run very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `git-clone(1)` but `git-archive(1)` (at least at the end). It also contains the revision that was archived and you can have markers in the file which contains the revision, e.g. create a flag-file.

For repositories you need a full clone, clone at the same time (or change the metadata after clone to the baseline).

Normally full clones *should* not be specifically necessary. If, you can also consider a tar-pipe in the process in which you take care to streamline the result so that the cache stays effective (only invalidate when needed).